# Autohotkey string - Bring segement to front

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to bring words with something in front of them to the front.

For example, turn `bla bla foobla` into `foobla bla bla` - put the word with foo in the front.

This would be quite easy with another language with stronger string manipulation functions, however I need to use AutoHotKey for functions that it provides.

Right now, I'm thinking of splitting the string into words (split by ' '), but I'm not even sure if I can find out the length of an 'array' in AHK.

Is doing this even possible in AHK?

Comment: What are these 'stronger string manipulation functions' that AHK is lacking, which you would use for this? If you provide an example I'll duplicate it using AHK.

Answer (score -1):

```
string := "bla bla fooble"
arr := StrSplit(string, " ")
msgbox % "the number of elements: " arr.maxindex()
removed := arr.remove(arr.maxindex())
arr.insert(1, removed)
For k, v in arr {
    output .= k ": " v "`n"
}
msgbox % output

StrSplit(ByRef InputVar, Delimiters="", OmitChars="") {
   o := []
   Loop, Parse, InputVar, % Delimiters, % OmitChars
      o.Insert(A_LoopField)
   return o
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't address: `"I would like to bring words with something in front of them to the front."`
it roughly addresses: `"I would like to move the last word in a string to the front of the string."`

Comment: If there is a legitimate reason for creating your own function rather than using the built in StringSplit command (I don't see one) then please include the reason. If you use code that is dependent on AHK_L [(listed as Object)](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/AHKL_Features.htm) then please include that information in the answer. Both points are general advice because you won't need to split the string or use AHK_L features to answer this question.

Comment: The example does address `to bring words with something in front of them to the front.` It's up to the person who adapts it. Use the latest AutoHotkey version to use objects. The built in function StringSplit is rather confusing as it uses derefs and it is not recommended. Use objects instead.